# scp from shell_exec not working

Tags: php

I want to send on the  server  the config file when I register new user. I do this on my php file:

```
$command = "scp -B -i $priv_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $tmp_file $user@$host:/home/asterisk/etc/asterisk/$filename 2>&1";
shell_exec($command);
```

But I have exception `Permission denied (publickey,password).lost connection`

What's wrong?

Comment: Depending on how those variables are set this can be a very risky bit of code from a security perspective.

Comment: path "/home/asterisk/etc/asterisk/ " might not have permission to create file